# How to stop set Interval flickering using angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, setinterval

Here i am displaying the dynamic data i.e lat and long on the google maps and here i am applying the setInterval() below is my code:

```
this.timer = setInterval(()=>{this.getMapData();},30000);
```

here the issue is when ever the data is updating or calling the this.getMapData() then the map is also flickering.Is It possible to update the data for every 30 sec with out flickering the div/map

```
getMapData() {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.serv.getMapData(this.ds, this.ln).subscribe(res => {
      this.spinner.hide();
      this.deleteMarkers();


      if (res.Data && res.Data.length > 0) {

        this.mapData = res.Data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.mapData));


        if (this.mapData != null && this.mapData.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.mapData.length; i++) {
            var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(this.mapData[i].latitude), lng: parseFloat(this.mapData[i].longitude)};
            this.addMarker(latlng, this.mapObject, this.mapData[i].Name);
            this.markerName = this.mapData[i].Name;


          }
        }
      } else {

        this.toastr.error('No Data Found', 'Oops!');
      }

    },err=>{
      this.spinner.hide();
    });


  }




 addMarker(latlng, mapobj, markerLabel) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      label: '',
      map: mapobj,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    });





var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: markerLabel
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
 // infowindow.open(Map,marker);
});



 infowindow.open(Map,marker);





   // This is for set postion for the marker after getting dynamic data it posittions to the point
   mapobj.setZoom(17);
   mapobj.panTo(marker.position);
    this.markers.push(marker);
  }



// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
  setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
      this.markers[i].setMap(map);

    }
  }

  // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
  clearMarkers() {
    this.setMapOnAll(null);
  }


  // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
  deleteMarkers() {
    this.clearMarkers();
    this.markers = [];
  }
```

Comment: how are you getting the ``getMapData()`` ? if you are using rxjs , you can use ``interval`` operator to fetch data after fixed interval

Comment: I am calling a  service from that getMapData() its Dynamic

Comment: can you post the definition of ``getMapData()`` ??

Comment: Sure i have updated the question please check it

Comment: you are creating the marker again and again everytime ``getMapData()`` is called , which is causing your map to flicker. Why don't you just do a ``setPosition()`` on that marker ?

Comment: here my lat and lang changes everytime i mean for every 30 sec the lat and long changes so i applied that

Comment: ``setPosition()`` will change your marker location to whatever location you'll provide and the marker position is updated on the map .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166869/discussion-between-madpop-and-cruelengine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion : 
`inside the addMarker()` ,

```
if(this.marker != null){
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      label: '',
      map: mapobj,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    });
   }
   else{
     this.marker.setPosition(latlng);
   }
```

So at first it will check if marker is `null` .If it is `null` then a new marker object is created . If not , then the marker's position is changed to the dynamic `latlng`.

So your , map flickering issue will be resolved as only the marker position is changing . Also remove the `this.deleteMarkers()` as you are changing position now , there is no need of deleting the marker from map.

Now , instead of using a setInterval , you can use rxjs operator `interval` to call the service and fetch data once in 30 seconds or whatever your time is .

To do this , inside your service do something like this :

```
return Observable.interval(30000).flatMap(()=>{ 
  return this.http.get(url + data+'/LocationId='+ param).map(res => { 
     return res.json(); 
  }); 
)};
```

**EDIT**

You'll need the following imports :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap`;
```

Comment: There is only one issue with approach suppose if i choose driver 1 from select list then it is returning that its fine but when i choose driver2 also it is displaying both driver1 and driver2 when refreshing the data

Comment: All you have to do is clear the clear the map marker , and then load the next marker(if you want to show only 1 marker ) . If you are looking at loading multiple markers , you can create Map of marker objects . This operation has to be done when select option changes its value.